# Build a df from two other df based on 0,1 in the df1 and the values in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dfs. one df has only 1 and 0 **(df_one_zero**). and another one has the different values **df_value_total**. These two has thousand rows and columns!

The first column of each df is the id and we dont want to change that at all.

I want to move with sliding window of 5 through the columns. so, each window I want to work with these two: df_one_zero_window, df_value_window.

In each window,the column which 1's started and ended is important.

Then I want to create another df_out with the same shape to the df_one_zero(initially is set to zero), consider that in column col the 1 started and ended in col_end,

put the value in **df_out (row, col-1) = df_value_window(row, col-1)-df_value_window(row, col)**, and other values are zero.(if the 1 started at index 0, or end at the last column then its ok. it does not need to put value for that)
Also, if the 1 in df_one_zero_window ended at col_end, then **df_out(row, col_end+1) = df_value_window(row,col_end+1)-df_value_window(row,col_end)**. In the following dfs, I want to create the df_out= df2. The values in df_value_total are very diverse and here I only select some easy number in my df.

```
## only has zero and 1
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df['0'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['1'] = [1, 0, 1]
df['2'] = [1, 1, 1]
df['3'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['4'] = [0, 0, 0]

df['5'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['6'] = [0, 1, 1]
df['7'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['8'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['9'] = [0, 0, 0]

df['10'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['11'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['12'] = [1, 1, 1]
df['13'] = [1, 0, 0]
df['14'] = [0, 0, 0]

df['15'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['16'] = [0, 1, 1]
df['17'] = [1, 1, 0]
df['18'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['19'] = [0, 0, 0]


## this is that which has different values
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['id'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df1['0'] = [4, 0, 9]
df1['1'] = [0, 0, 1]
df1['2'] = [1, 1, 3]
df1['3'] = [6, 2, 0]
df1['4'] = [0, 0, 0]

df1['5'] = [0, 5, 0]
df1['6'] = [0, 1, 2]
df1['7'] = [0, 0, 1]
df1['8'] = [0, 0, 3]
df1['9'] = [0, 0, 0]

df1['10'] = [0, 0, 0]
df1['11'] = [0, 0, 1]
df1['12'] = [1, 1, 1]
df1['13'] = [1, 3, 4]
df1['14'] = [9, 0, 0]

df1['15'] = [0, 0, 0]
df1['16'] = [2, 1, 1]
df1['17'] = [1, 1, 4]
df1['18'] = [0, 5, 0]
df1['19'] = [0, 0, 0]
```

I tried to do some parts, but I couldn't track where the 1 is finished and also I think it is not optimum!Can you please help me with that?

```
def generate_df_out(df_one_zero, df_value_total, window_size=5):


    for col in range(1, len(df_one_zero.columns), window_size):
        
        df1_window = df_one_zero.iloc[:, col:col + window_size]
        
        df_value_window = df_value_total.iloc[:, col:col + window_size]
        
        for row in range(df1_window.shape[0]):
            
            start_idx = 0
            
            for col in range(window_size):
            
                if df1_window.iloc[row, col] == 1 and start_idx==0:
                    
                    df_out.iloc[row, col-1] = df_value_window.iloc[row, col] - df_value_window.iloc[row, col-1]
                
                    start_idx += col

    return df_out


df_out = generate_df_out(df, df1)
```

The output I want is like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['id'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df2['0'] = [4, 0, 8]
df2['1'] = [0, -1, 0]
df2['2'] = [0, 1, 0]
df2['3'] = [5, 1, -1]
df2['4'] = [0, 0, 0]
​
df2['5'] = [0, 4, -1]
df2['6'] = [0, 0, 0]
df2['7'] = [0, -1, 0]
df2['8'] = [0, 0, 2]
df2['9'] = [0, 0, 0]
​
df2['10'] = [0, 0, -1]
df2['11'] = [-1, -1, 0]
df2['12'] = [0, 0, 0]
df2['13'] = [0, 2, 3]
df2['14'] = [9, 0, 0]
​
df2['15'] = [0, -1, -1]
df2['16'] = [1, 0, 0]
df2['17'] = [0, 0, 3]
df2['18'] = [-1, 4, 0]
df2['19'] = [0, 0, 0]
df2
id  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   a   4   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   -1  1   1   9   0   1   0   -1  0
1   b   0   -1  1   1   0   4   0   -1  0   ... 0   -1  0   2   0   -1  0   0   4   0
2   c   8   0   0   -1  0   -1  0   0   2   ... -1  0   0   3   0   -1  0   3   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need a function that processes each window and updates `df_out` accordingly. The function should iterate over each window, track the start and end of sequences of 1s in `df_one_zero`, and compute the differences in `df_value_total` based on these indices. Following is the updated function:

```py
def generate_df_out(df_one_zero, df_value_total, window_size=5):
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df_one_zero.index, columns=df_one_zero.columns)
    df_out['id'] = df_one_zero['id']

    for col in range(1, len(df_one_zero.columns), window_size):
        for row in range(df_one_zero.shape[0]):
            sequence_started = False

            for c in range(col, min(col + window_size, len(df_one_zero.columns))):
                if df_one_zero.iloc[row, c] == 1:
                    if not sequence_started:
                        if c > 1:  # Check for the start of the sequence
                            df_out.iloc[row, c - 1] = df_value_total.iloc[row, c - 1] - df_value_total.iloc[row, c]
                        sequence_started = True

                    if c + 1 < len(df_one_zero.columns) and df_one_zero.iloc[row, c + 1] == 0:
                        df_out.iloc[row, c + 1] = df_value_total.iloc[row, c + 1] - df_value_total.iloc[row, c]

    return df_out
```

Sample Run:

```py
import pandas as pd

## only has zero and 1
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df['0'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['1'] = [1, 0, 1]
df['2'] = [1, 1, 1]
df['3'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['4'] = [0, 0, 0]

df['5'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['6'] = [0, 1, 1]
df['7'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['8'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['9'] = [0, 0, 0]

df['10'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['11'] = [0, 0, 1]
df['12'] = [1, 1, 1]
df['13'] = [1, 0, 0]
df['14'] = [0, 0, 0]

df['15'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['16'] = [0, 1, 1]
df['17'] = [1, 1, 0]
df['18'] = [0, 0, 0]
df['19'] = [0, 0, 0]


## this is that which has different values
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['id'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df1['0'] = [4, 0, 9]
df1['1'] = [0, 0, 1]
df1['2'] = [1, 1, 3]
df1['3'] = [6, 2, 0]
df1['4'] = [0, 0, 0]

df1['5'] = [0, 5, 0]
df1['6'] = [0, 1, 2]
df1['7'] = [0, 0, 1]
df1['8'] = [0, 0, 3]
df1['9'] = [0, 0, 0]

df1['10'] = [0, 0, 0]
df1['11'] = [0, 0, 1]
df1['12'] = [1, 1, 1]
df1['13'] = [1, 3, 4]
df1['14'] = [9, 0, 0]

df1['15'] = [0, 0, 0]
df1['16'] = [2, 1, 1]
df1['17'] = [1, 1, 4]
df1['18'] = [0, 5, 0]
df1['19'] = [0, 0, 0]




def generate_df_out(df_one_zero, df_value_total, window_size=5):
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(0, index=df_one_zero.index, columns=df_one_zero.columns)
    df_out['id'] = df_one_zero['id']

    for col in range(1, len(df_one_zero.columns), window_size):
        for row in range(df_one_zero.shape[0]):
            sequence_started = False

            for c in range(col, min(col + window_size, len(df_one_zero.columns))):
                if df_one_zero.iloc[row, c] == 1:
                    if not sequence_started:
                        if c > 1:  # Check for the start of the sequence
                            df_out.iloc[row, c - 1] = df_value_total.iloc[row, c - 1] - df_value_total.iloc[row, c]
                        sequence_started = True

                    if c + 1 < len(df_one_zero.columns) and df_one_zero.iloc[row, c + 1] == 0:
                        df_out.iloc[row, c + 1] = df_value_total.iloc[row, c + 1] - df_value_total.iloc[row, c]

    return df_out

# Example usage
df_out = generate_df_out(df, df1)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  id  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0  a  4  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  -1   0   0   8   0   1   0  -1   0
1  b  0 -1  0  1  0  4  0 -1  0  0   0  -1   0   2   0  -1   0   0   4   0
2  c  8  0  0 -3  0 -2  0  0  2  0  -1   0   0   3   0  -1   0   3   0   0
```